# Intersect between two List<int[]>

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, intersection

I want to get the intersection of the following two lists.

```
List<int[]> list1 = new List<int[]>
{
    new int[] { 0, 0, 0, },
    new int[] { 1, 1, 1, }
};

List<int[]> list2 = new List<int[]>
{
    new int[] { 1, 1, 1, },
    new int[] { 2, 2, 2, }
};
```

But when I try

```
List<int[]> intersection = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

The intersection returns empty. When I try this exact setup with two `List<int>` (not array) it works as expected.

This is my first time using Linq. How can I get this intersection?

Comment: You will have to provide a custom equality comparer that compares the array contents. The default equality comparer is reference comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default comparer used for checking equality is a **reference comparison**.
This default is not suited for comparing the content of your arrays.

You can achieve what you need by using a **custom comparer** (derived from [`IEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7)), that actually compares the content of the arrays:

```
// Custom comparer:
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
{
    public bool Equals(int[] a, int[] b) 
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, b)) return true; 
        if (a is null) return false; 
        if (b is null) return false;
        return a.SequenceEqual(b); 
    }
    public int  GetHashCode(int[] a)     
    { 
        return a.Aggregate(1, (acc, item) => acc * item); 
    }
}
```

Then you can use for the intersection:

```
List<int[]> list1 = new List<int[]>
            {
                new int[] { 0, 0, 0, },
                new int[] { 1, 1, 1, }
            };

List<int[]> list2 = new List<int[]>
            {
                new int[] { 1, 1, 1, },
                new int[] { 2, 2, 2, }
            };

// Intersection with custom comparer:
//------------------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv----------
List<int[]> intersection = list1.Intersect(list2, new MyComparer()).ToList();

foreach (var list in intersection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", string.Join(", ", list));
}
```

Output:

```
1, 1, 1
```

**Note:**
My implementation of `GetHashCode` is just a trivial one you might need to refine.
You can see @Oliver's comment below regarding how to improve it (it requires the Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode NuGet for `HashCode`).
Another issue with my `GetHashCode` is that it requires to traverse the whole array. It can also overflow especially (easily) when the arrays are long. As commented by @Dmitry Bychenko, you can use the following instead (also requires `HashCode` from Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode):

```
return HashCode.Combine(a.DefaultIfEmpty().Take(4));
```

This will take at most 4 items into consideration and let .Net combine them.

Comment: _Easiest_ way to improve `GetHashCode()` would be `var hash = new HashCode(); foreach() { hash.Add(i); }; return hash.ToHashCode();`

Comment: @Oliver thanks, updated `Equals`. Regarding `GetHashCode` - I'll leave that for the OP because it requires a NuGet and will make my answer not self-contained.

Comment: Since lists can be *long*, `return a.Aggregate(1, (acc, item) => acc * item);` can be *slow* (it aggregates the *entire* litst); another problem is *integer overflow*: `acc * item` can exceed `int.MaxValue` and exception can be thrown (it depends on project settings). I suggest `return HashCode.Combine(value.DefaultIfEmpty().Take(4));` instead - we take at most 4 items into consideration and let .Net combine them

Comment: @DmitryBychenko good  point. Added a note.

Answer (score 4):

Approach with `Where()` and `Any()`

You can compare the equality of lists / arrays and every object that inherits `IEnumerable` with `SequenceEqual`

```
List<int[]> intersection = list1.Where(l1 => list2.Any(l2=> l1.SequenceEqual(l2))).ToList();
```